# How to check wether the component is UIView or UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiview

Hi in my application i have an array. In that i have number of UIView and UIImageView Components, and i want to fetch each component from that array and have to know wether that is imageview or view, if that is imageview i have to change the image for that imageview.But i dont have any idea how to know wether the component is imageview or view. If any one know please let me know the way to recognize the component type. Please help me in this issue.

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++){
   // here i have to know wether the component is imageview or view and based on that i have to do below operations 
   UIView *view1=[array objectAtIndex:i];
   NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
   if (130==view1.tag){
       view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    UIImageView *image1=[array objectAtIndex:i];
    if (132==image1.tag){
       image1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Approve2.png"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `isKindOfClass`

Example:

```
if ( [originalValue isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] ){

   UIImageView *myImageView = (UIImageView *)originalValue;

}
```

Comment: hi Ram thanks a lot your quick reply save me from troubles... thanks a lot ram...

Comment: Hi can help me some more based on ur suggestions i had change my code as such

Comment: hi ram i need ur help once again. now the UIimageview is also considering as a UIview class by the compiler. PLease let me know why it is happening.

Comment: dont blame compiler.It will do perfect.. check ur code well.. :)

Comment: and another method if ( [originalValue isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] ){

   UIView *myView = (UIView *)originalValue;

}

Comment: hi ram i tried still no use. actually i have to conditions             if ( [[patternAnnotationsArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] )
  else if ( [[patternAnnotationsArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] ) second condition is not at all exicuting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26305/discussion-between-user2119204-and-ramshad)

Answer (score -1):

You can check by class introspection

Try this

```
if( [obj1 class] == [obj2 class] ){

   //same class
}
```

---

Few extra things that you may feel handy

> ```
> Class Introspection
> ·  Determine whether an objective-C object is an instance of a class
>         [obj isMemberOfClass:someClass];
> ·  Determine whether an objective-C object is an instance of a class or its descendants
>         [obj isKindOfClass:someClass];
> ·  The version of a class
>         [MyString version]
> ·  Find the class of an Objective-C object
>         Class c = [obj1 class]; 
>         Class c = [NSString class];
> ·  Verify 2 Objective-C objects are of the same class
>         [obj1 class] == [obj2 class]
> ```

Comment: @user2119204 Few more stuffs that may come handy to you.

Comment: Hi anoop thank u so much for ur reply. Can you please provide one example for this procedure like can u compare uiview and uiimageview.it will help me a lot.

Comment: @user2119204: I think you are done with your problem as you have accepted Ram's answer?