# Get a child from a certain class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a ViewController  `@interface PagerViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>` where I add other ViewControllers as a child ( `addChildViewController` ) Those ViewControllers that I add are from difference classes but they all inherit from UIViewController. I can loop thru them using this code:

```
    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i<(unsigned int)[_app.windows count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"%@",((MyViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i]).getQAnswer);

}
```

However, I always need to cast it to the correct one (in the above example I cast it to MyViewController. The problem is that there are many childs from different classes on it, so what if I only want the childs from the class "anotherViewController" instead of "MyViewController"?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452663/how-to-check-wether-the-component-is-uiview-or-uiimageview/15452680#15452680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isKindOfClass to filter those objects which are instances of a certain class. for example:

```
if ([object isKindOfClass:[anotherViewController class]]) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it needs to be like this then: if ([[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[anotherViewController class]])

Comment: Sure, you can use it however you need ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you want objects from certain class, use `isMemberOfClass:`, if you want to include descendant classes, use `isKindOfClass:`.
E.g. if arr is NSMutableArray then `[arr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]` is TRUE and`[arr isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]` is FALSE.